# not able to get data in karma function from controller defer statement

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine, angular-services

```
            /*This is my cart service function:*/
            getCheckoutItems: function() {
                            var defer = $q.defer();
                            var response = {
                                result: true,
                                data: '',
                                err: ''
                            };
                            if (!angular.isUndefined(productListSample)) {
                                response.data = productListSample;
                                defer.resolve(response);
                            } else {
                                response.result = false;
                                response.err = 'error';
                                defer.reject(response);
                            }
                            return defer.promise;
                        }
        /*This is my controller function:*/
         $scope.cart = {
                    items: [],
                    phoneNo: ''
                };

                $scope.getCheckoutItems = function() {
                    CartService.getCheckoutItems().then(function(result) {
                        $scope.cart.items = result.data;
                                  }, function(err) {
                        /*
                         *  Todo: handle when service fails to retrieve data.
                         */
                    });
                };

    /* This is karma test function */
     it('get checkout items', inject(function($controller) {
        $controller('Ctrl', {
          $scope: scope
        });
        scope.getCheckoutItems();
        console.log(scope.cart);

      }));
```

> I am not getting cart items in karma test.
>   controller calls service for getting data in async. this process is 
>   handled by angular promise.but problem with writing test case               > because controller function returns before getting data from        > service. 
>   how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
scope.getCheckoutItems();
console.log(scope.cart);
```

by

```
scope.getCheckoutItems();
scope.$apply();
console.log(scope.cart);
```

Promise callbacks are called when the scope is $applied.

Comment: I have doubt with scope.$apply() what exactly it do?

Comment: In that specific case, it will make sure the callbacks are called. For a full description of what $apply() does, read the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope